# How to declare a string in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, string, nsstring

How do I declare a simple string "test" to a variable?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

```
NSString *testString = @"test";
```

Comment: That was the answer I was looking for. Although the answer the Carl Norum is very detailed.

Comment: The answer is clearly explained in Carl Norum's answer. `@"aString"` produces an NSString object. `"aString"` is a C string, which is just an array of characters.

Comment: Why is it that in order to use the string variable we have to use pointer while NSInteger can be declared without one? e.g `NSInteger one = 1`

Comment: An `NSString` in Objective-C is an object, whereas `NSInteger` is a primitive type. Objects are always allocated on the heap, whereas primitives can be allocated on the stack. Most importantly, the reason there’s a pointer for a string is that objects are passed by _reference_ whereas primitives are passed by _value_.

Answer (score 50):

A C string is just like in C.

```
char myCString[] = "test";
```

An NSString uses the `@` character:

```
NSString *myNSString = @"test";
```

If you need to manage the NSString's memory:

```
NSString *myNSString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"test"];
NSString *myRetainedNSString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"test"];
```

Or if you need an editable string:

```
NSMutableString *myMutableString = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"test"];
```

You can read more from the [Apple NSString documentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html).

Comment: What is the different beween NSString and char?

Comment: `char` is a native C type, and `NSString`/`NSMutableString` are classes for managing strings in Cocoa/Objective-C. They don't really bear much relationship to a normal C string (array of `char`) at all. You should check out some basic "how-to" Objective-C documentation to get started.

Comment: @powtac, the `@` is part of Objective-C syntax.  In this case it indicates that the string literal is an NSString, not a regular C style string literal.

Answer (score 12):

Standard string assignment can be done like so:

```
NSString *myTestString = @"abc123";
```

**In addition to the basic allocation there are a whole lot of methods you get when using the NSString Class that you don't get with the Standard Char[] array. That is why Objective programming is better!**

For instance filling a string with the contents of a html webpage, with a single line of code!**

Creating and Initializing Strings

```
+ string
– init
– initWithBytes:length:encoding:
– initWithBytesNoCopy:length:encoding:freeWhenDone:
– initWithCharacters:length:
– initWithCharactersNoCopy:length:freeWhenDone:
– initWithString:
– initWithCString:encoding:
– initWithUTF8String:
– initWithFormat:
– initWithFormat:arguments:
– initWithFormat:locale:
– initWithFormat:locale:arguments:
– initWithData:encoding:
+ stringWithFormat:
+ localizedStringWithFormat:
+ stringWithCharacters:length:
+ stringWithString:
+ stringWithCString:encoding:
+ stringWithUTF8String:
```

Creating and Initializing a String from a File

```
+ stringWithContentsOfFile:encoding:error:
– initWithContentsOfFile:encoding:error:
+ stringWithContentsOfFile:usedEncoding:error:
– initWithContentsOfFile:usedEncoding:error:
```

Creating and Initializing a String from an URL

```
+ stringWithContentsOfURL:encoding:error:
– initWithContentsOfURL:encoding:error:
+ stringWithContentsOfURL:usedEncoding:error:
– initWithContentsOfURL:usedEncoding:error:
```

If you need a string where you can edit its buffer you want to look at:

```
NSMutableString
```